# Plausible: has selector for invalid input CSS?

Tags: css

I have my element like this:

```
const Input = (props: InputProps) => (
  <div className={classes.InputElement}>
    <input {...props} />
  </div>
)
```

```
.InputElement::after:has(input:invalid) {
  content: 'Hello world';
  color: red;
}
```

But the code doesn't behave as intended. I was wondering if this is actually even feasible?

Comment: "But the code doesn't behave as intended" doesn't tell us what the issue is, btw. I assume you're trying to add an after pseudo element to .InputElement if the input element has `invalid`, in such case: `.InputElement:has(input:invalid)::after`.

Comment: Ah you told exactly what I wanted. Can you please add this in answer so that I can mark it and close the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're trying to add an after pseudo element to .InputElement if the input element has invalid, in such case: `.InputElement:has(input:invalid)::after`.

Otherwise you're querying for when the after pseudo element has `input:invalid` which it can't.